# are network libraries exist in FLTK c++ like FTP or TCP

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, fltk

I'm trying to make a FTP client using Fltk c++
and i can't find any network classes/libraries to deal with fltk
so; does fltk have any classes?
(Sorry For Bad English)
and thanks

Comment: There is no network support in FLTK - it is just a graphics library

Comment: thx; how can i use linux sockets with fltk???,

Comment: Depends what you want to do: just look for `sockets example C++ linux` on your favourite search engine.  Put that on a different thread, use it to write to global memory and use your fltk thread to read from global memory.

Comment: thanks!but i want to make ftp client? i didn't see anything about it;

Comment: Try looking up `ftp client linux c`